Name of metric used by Friedmann
In his original paper, Friedmann used the following dynamic and symmetrical metric:
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=a(t)^2\left(\mathrm{d}\chi^2+\sin (\chi)^2\left(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin (\theta)^2 \mathrm{d}\phi^2\right)\right)-c \mathrm{d}t^2$$
Does this metric have a name? What space-time property makes it different from the Robertson-Walker metric?

You probably missed a power of $2$ in the $c$ next to $dt^2$.

Same metric but different variables

This is just the Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric for a spatially closed universe ($k=1$ in modern notation). In other words, it is a particular case of the FLRW metric. The three-dimensional metric
$$\mathrm{d}l^2 = \mathrm{d}\chi^2+\sin (\chi)^2\left(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin (\theta)^2 \mathrm{d}\phi^2\right)$$
is just the standard round metric on the $3$-sphere in hyperspherical coordinates.
